# Global variable is not updated in the main function when it is changed inside another function having semaphore locks

Tags: c, variables, global, semaphore

My code logic goes like this:

```
int count =0;
main()
{
    //Child processes invoked 
    { 
        //Call Function()
    }
    //Sleep(5)
    //Print(count)
}

Function()
{ 
    //Semaphore lock
    //Count ++ //to count the number of semaphore locks 
    //Semaphore unlock
    //Print(count) //count value updated to some value 30000
}
```

Output of `count` inside `main()` function: `0`

Inside `Function()`, `count` is incremented to the number of locks. (It is printed multiple times throughout the increments because the function is called by multiple child processes.) `count`: `-1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 30000`.

Note: `count` is not the semaphore variable.

My doubt: As `count` is a global variable, its value is supposed to be updated inside `Function()` and printed in the `main()` function. But it is not!  `count` in `main()` function is `0`.

So, how do I print the final count value just one time?

Comment: show you main please. my doubt is you created a child process by `fork` and hoped `count` would be changed by child shown in main. but notice that `count` is not shared. if you do that, you were wrong.

Comment: You need to **show your real code**. In particular, what kind of semaphore is this?

Comment: Child *process* would be a different process. Unless you set up shared memory, it does not share memory with any other process, including parent, so changing variables in either is not seen by the other. If you want that, use threads.

Comment: As others have mentioned, there's really no point showing what you think your code "logic" is, when you already know your code doesn't work. Reduce your problem to a minimum code example that reproduces the problem and post that actual code.

Comment: a 'child' process gets a COPY of the data, not access to the original data.  So the child process is incrementing its' copy and printing it.  While the main process is still looking at the (unchanged) original variable.